# I want to pass my Sidebar to some views in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-component, react-dom

Im building this app for a shop, I have the Login already working but I want that when Login in app, it shows the Sidebar, and when choosing an option, the Sidebar may not dissapear only the content part should change, but it doesn't, heres what I have:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Login from './components/Login'
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import Administrar from './components/Productos/Administrar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact render={ props => (<Login {...props} />)}></Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard" exact render={ props => (<Dashboard {...props} />)}></Route>
          
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Dashboard.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Sidebar from '../template/Sidebar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import {ApiUrl} from '../services/apirest'
import Administrar from './Productos/Administrar'

const SideAndNavbar = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Sidebar/>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/productos/administrar" exact component={ props => (<Administrar {...props} />)}></Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

const Relog = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Relogeate pá</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default function Dashboard() {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        obtenerUsuario()
    }, [])

    const obtenerUsuario = async () => {
        let url = ApiUrl + "/usuario";
        await axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                setUser(response.data.user)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    return (
        (user ? <SideAndNavbar/>: <Relog/>)
    );
}
```

Login.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import toast, {Toaster} from 'react-hot-toast'
import logo from '../assets/img/img-01.png'
import axios from 'axios'
import {ApiUrl} from '../services/apirest'

class Login extends Component {
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    state = {
        form:{
            "email": "",
            "password": ""
        },
    }

    manejadorChange = async(e) =>{
        await this.setState({
            form: {
                ...this.state.form,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }
        })
    }

    manejadorBoton = () => {
        let url = ApiUrl + "/auth/logearse";
        axios.post(url, this.state.form)
            .then(response => {
                if(response.data.status === "OK"){
                    localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
                    /*
                    this.props.history.push({
                        pathname: '/dashboard',
                        state: response.data.user
                    })
                    */
                   this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
                }else{
                    toast.error(response.data.message);
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                toast.error("Error al conectarse con el servidor");
            })
    }

    manejadorSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Toaster position="top-center" reverseOrder={false}/>
                <div className="limiter">
                    <div className="container-login100">
                        <div className="wrap-login100">
                            
                            <div className="login100-pic">
                                <img src={logo} alt="Imagen"/>
                            </div>

                            <form className="login100-form validate-form" onSubmit={this.manejadorSubmit}>
                                <span className="login100-form-title">
                                    Ingreso de Usuario
                                </span>

                                <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                                    <input className="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={this.manejadorChange}/>
                                    <span className="focus-input100"></span>
                                    <span className="symbol-input100">
                                        <i className="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div className="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                                    <input className="input100" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.manejadorChange}/>
                                    <span className="focus-input100"></span>
                                    <span className="symbol-input100">
                                        <i className="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div className="container-login100-form-btn">
                                    <button className="login100-form-btn" onClick={this.manejadorBoton}>
                                        Ingresar
                                    </button>
                                </div>

                                <div className="text-center p-t-56">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

What can I do? Here is some pics:

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to achieve some heavy Routing without the help of any state management, There are few anti patterns in your current setup. I have a few suggestions that will help you achieve what you are trying to implement.

- Firstly Your application routing is setup in a ambiguous way. If you see the routing implementation looks like a nested Routing setup. but the URl you are used is `/productos/administrar` this route in terms of relativity is rendered from the `/` base URL.
- Your Home(Entry point of the application APP.js) is setup with a parent Router, The router now reads your URL and Tries to render a component. but sees that in the parent Route there is no such URL.
- Now if you see carefully your `dashboard` component is setup to render `<SideNav>`, to render the sidenav on the `/productos/administrar` route you should firstly go through the `dashboard` component.
- in your current setup the `dashboard` component is missed and directly the `Admin` component is rendered at the root of the router.

> I would want you to follow the `Layout Pattern` where you can stuff the sidenav and topnav (if you have any) along with a main section which render the childrens passed to the component, and on each route call this Layout Component with children props.

this way you ensure the Layout is visible on every route. But that's a long way . ***If you want a quick fix is to implement proper nested Routing*** using `useRouterMatch()` to pass the current route down the component tree. Now change the dashboard component to something like this

```js
    const SideAndNavbar = ({match}) => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
              // Make sure you user the match props in Sidebar to append he correct URl for nesting to the Link tag , for example (<Link to={`${match.url}/productos/administrar`}>GO to Admin</Link>)
                <Sidebar match={match}/>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path={`${match.path}/productos/administrar`} exact component={ props => (<Administrar {...props} />)}></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    const Relog = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Relogeate pá</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default function Dashboard() {

        const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
        let match = useRouteMatch();
        useEffect(() => {
            obtenerUsuario()
        }, [])

        const obtenerUsuario = async () => {
            let url = ApiUrl + "/usuario";
            await axios.get(url)
                .then(response => {
                    setUser(response.data.user)
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }

        return (
            (user ? <SideAndNavbar match={match} />: <Relog/>)
        );
    }
```

[For more info on this topic see the official documentation of React Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/2nd-example-nested-routing)